# Algorithm for tree data in php codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, php-5.6

I am having trouble creating a category tree structure in php and codeigniter ramework environments.

So now I want the structure of the data.

Data Example:

```
{
    "category": [
        {
            "id"      : "1",
            "text"    : "test1"
            "children": false,
        }, {
            "id"      : "2",
            "text"    : "test2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "children": false,
                    "id"      : "3",
                    "text"    : "test3"
                }, {
                    "children": false,
                    "id"      : "4",
                    "text"    : "test4"
                }, {
                    "children": false,
                    "id"      : "5",
                    "text"    : "test5"
                }, {
                    "children": false,
                    "id"      : "6",
                    "text"    : "test7"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm having trouble creating an array for each json object's children

The query I am trying:

```
 public function setCategoryTree($categoryUp = null)
  {
    $param = array();

    $query = ' SELECT id, name, categoryUp
                 FROM categoryTable 
                  WHERE categoryUp = ? ';


    return $this->commerce_db->query($query)->result();
  }
```

The controller I'm trying to:

```
  public function getCategoryTree(){
    $this->load->model('category_m');
    $result = $this->category_m->setCategoryTree();
    $resultData = array();

    foreach($result as $value) {
      $treeTmpData = array();
      $treeTmpData['id'] = $value->id;
      $treeTmpData['text'] = $value->text;
      $treeTmpData['children'] = ????      
      $resultData[] = $treeTmpData;
    }

    echo json_encode($resultData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

  }
```

Good luck to me

Comment: Please provide structure of categoryTable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for your purpose. I use recursion for getting childern.

Table structure is :

```
CREATE TABLE `categorytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Model methods are:

```
public function setCategoryTree() {
        $categories = array();
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT id, name as text, parent_id as children FROM categoryTable WHERE parent_id IS NULL');
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $child = $this->getChilderen($row->id);
            if (count($child) > 0) {
                $row->children = $child;
            } else {
                $row->children = false;
            }
            $categories[] = $row;
        }
        return $categories;
    }

    private function getChilderen($parentId) {
        $child = array();
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT id, name as text, parent_id as children FROM categoryTable WHERE parent_id = ' . $parentId);
        if (count($query->result()) > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $i => $row) {
                if ($row->children > 0) {
                    $row->children = $this->getChilderen($row->id);
                }
                $child[$i] = $row;
            }
            return $child;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Controller code:

```
public function getCategoryTree(){
    $this->load->model('category_m');
    $resultData = $this->category_m->setCategoryTree();
    echo json_encode($resultData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

Hope, that will help you. Let me know if you stuck somewhere.